# O usuário Comunidade analisou e aprovou uma edição

Tags: suporte

Olhando a análise de uma pergunta, apareceu lá na lista de edições:

> Comunidade analisou 1 min atrás: Aprovar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até onde eu sei, esse usuário é um robô. O robô consegue avaliar edições?

Comment: É o Gabe disfarçado de bot.

Comment: @jbueno na verdade é o contrário, o Gabe é o Comunidade disfarçado de CM. Note que ele fica 24/7 no chat, e responde instantaneamente mesmo quando não colocamos @ no nome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, consegue :)

Ele tem critérios bem objetivos. Nesse caso, se não me engano, ocorreu porque o Ack Lay resolveu **editar**, então o Comunidade aprovou a edição por ele, afinal precisa de duas aprovações. Tem algumas situações que ele aprova, não saberia dizer todas. Uma delas é se o autor aprova.